# Is it possible to define two variants of an XSD schema in one file and easily switch when validating different XML files?

Tags: xml, command-line, xsd-validation

I have a setting in which both the demand and the actual configuration of a system are stored as XML files. In principle, the structure of the corresponding `demand.xml` and `actual.xml` should be exactly the same, but for reasons beyond the scope of this question, the `actual.xml` contains some attributes about the system state that are outside the control of the user and therefore obviously not part of the `demand.xml`.

So, the `demand.xml` might look something like

```xml
<Configuration>
  <Actuator label="axis1">
    <ParamA>This_Value</ParamA>
    <ParamB>That_Value</ParamB>
  </Actuator>
...
</Configuration>
```

whereas the `actual.xml` would look like (assuming for simplicity that actual state matches demand state)

```xml
<Configuration>
   <Actuator label="axis1" connected="true">
      <ParamA>This_Value</ParamA>
      <ParamB>That_Value</ParamB>
   </Actuator>
...
</Configuration>
```

Now, I would like to validate both `demand.xml` and `actual.xml` using an XSD schema with a command-line tool such as `xmlstarlet`. Due to the design, the elements of `demand.xml` are a subset of those in `actual.xml` so it seems inefficient to write *two* XSD files. Instead, I would like to write only one for `actual.xml`.

**Question**: Is it possible to "switch off" certain elements from the XSD schema when validating `demand.xml` while applying the full schema when validating `actual.xml`?

I have looked at the options of `xmlstarlet` but didn't find any hint on how to achieve that goal. If `xmlstarlet` is not the right tool I am open to other suggestions, but ideally it would be a tool available from the standard package repositories for RHEL8.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming attributes in the XSD schema file are on the form,

```xml
<xsd:attribute name="label" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
<xsd:attribute name="connected" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
```

why not create a subset schema by removing the nodes which belong to
the superset only, for example:

```sh
if test "${xsdsubset}"
then xmlstarlet edit \
  -d '//xsd:complexType[@name="ActuatorType"]/xsd:attribute[@name="connected"]'
else cat -
fi < superset.xsd |
xmlstarlet validate --err --xsd /dev/stdin file1.xml file2.xml fileN.xml
```

Define the `xsdsubset` shell variable as non-empty to check the subset.

If the superset-only nodes can be identified by querying the .xsd
(via annotations?) you could even have `xmlstarlet select` generate
the `xmlstarlet edit` command.

Comment: Hm, generating the subset on-the-fly is an interesting idea. I will play around with it to see if that is a viable solution in my case, but it's certainly promising!